# Can i install a whole debian8 for arm in raspberry pi?

Tags: debian

Which iso can i download from

```
https://www.debian.org/CD/http-ftp/#stable
```

arm64 or armel ?

And dd the iso into my sd card to install os into raspberry pi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to run "real" Debian on a Raspberry Pi2 , but it involves some work
since it is not fully supported in Debian wheezy or jessie :

http://sjoerd.luon.net/posts/2015/02/debian-jessie-on-rpi2/

Answer (score 2):

That will not work for several reasons - the Pi is a 32 bit machine and has a unique kernel image and boot system.

The standard Raspbian image is based on Debian stable.  You can always download packages not in the image from the Raspbian repository.